# WikiData: filter mwapi results

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I am trying to write a sparql query that can retrieve all categories/items from a root and filter down only the ones that are of "human" type.

Using the query below, I can retrieve all categories & items for the category "Obama", but for some reason the filter isnt kicking in to narrow down the results from the service. In both my filter attempts the query timesout, but there shouldnt be that many items in the first place.

```
SELECT 
*
WHERE {
  # get all categories
  wd:Q76 wdt:P910 ?category .  
  ?link schema:about ?category; schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>; schema:name ?title .
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
     bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "en.wikipedia.org";
                     wikibase:api "Generator";
                     mwapi:generator "categorymembers";
                     mwapi:gcmtitle ?title;
                     mwapi:gcmprop "ids|title|type";
                     mwapi:gcmlimit "max".
     ?member wikibase:apiOutput mwapi:title.
     ?ns wikibase:apiOutput "@ns".
     ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item.
  }
  
  #filter results

  #attemp1: this times out
  #?item (wdt:P31) ?type
  #filter exists {?type wdt:P31 wd:Q5}
  
  #attemp2: this times out
  #?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5 
}
```

Comment: https://w.wiki/4fQe

Comment: Thanks! any chance you can elaborate how it works with "FILTER (bound(?item))" ? The item variable is already returned from  mwapi so why do we need to "bound" it?

Comment: "*The item variable is already returned from mwapi*" — see https://w.wiki/4hFb :)

Comment: So is it excluded from the final table unless we redefine the item variable after FILTER(bound)ing?